# How to make a 800 kHz digital signal reach 10 meters

Tags: circuit-design, signal, signal-integrity

I am running some addressable LED strips the SK6812 variant. Because i want to hide the power supply and the controller, the strips and controller is now situated about 10 meters away from each other. During testing the controller and strips were only 1 foot apart so the problem did not surface immediately, it was only when i installed the things where it dawned on me that I messed up.

The SK6812 runs on a 1-wire data, and operates at a frequency of  800 kHz (I tried lowering the frequency to 400 kHz and the result is still the same). There are 4 wires going to the led strip. 14 AWG for 5 V and GND, and a twisted pair (one wire is GND and the other is DATA) that is from a CAT6 Ethernet cable. From the mCu GPIO the voltage level is shifted up from 3V3 to 5V using this circuit.

[image]

What are my options in resolving this problem? I do have two constraints:

1. The controller and the led strip distance from each other is already fixed.
2. There must be no additional circuitry at the led strips, so signal redrivers that requires a transmitter and reciever are not allowed.

Comment: Do you have a scope? If so, post pictures of the signal a) with a 1 m cable and b) with a 10 m cable, so we can see the difference.

Comment: One part of the problem is that the level conversion circuit you have used can't possibly drive a 400 or 800 kHz signal, not for 10 meters of CAT6 which has about 50 pF of capacitance per meter, so thats about 0.5 nF. You could try a proper logic buffer that works with 3.3V input and has 5V output.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Sorry no, I do not own a scope.

Comment: Signal integrity issues are tough without a scope! If it worked at 1m, but not at 10m, then I'd look at reflection issues and/or line capacitance issues.  If it's capacitance, and you can't change your circuit, you're sunk!

Comment: @Justme I see, what other features of the buffer must have to increase the chances of it working? A quick search led me to this IC [SN75454](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75452b.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1632856049441&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fsn75452b0)

Comment: I'd say replace the buffer and try to create an impedance match using coaxial cable and a terminating resistors.

Comment: @Aaron I do have some arduino board lying around that i can turn into some very cheap scopes, will this suffice as a temporary work around? Its kind of difficult to borrow a scope right now due to covid restrictions

Comment: I can't post pictures from work computer, but I did a quick LTSpice sim, and with the 0.5nF from @Justme comment, using around 1k for the resistors might work.  You need to be able to push enough current to charge the cable capacitance, otherwise you just have a large RC filter killing your signal.

Comment: You might give a thought to a HDMI DDC/I2C level-shifter/redriver like a PCA9507.  They're designed to level shift and have an integrated active pull-up circuit.  400kHz might be pushing it but for less than $2, it's probably worth testing.

Comment: @vir As the bus is not open-collector, something suitable for I2C like PCA9507 is a completely wrong and extremely expensive for the task you can handle with less than a $0.40 part.

Comment: @Aaron I tried replacing the R15 resistor with 1k, sadly it didnt work. I did confirm that the strips were working by changing the wire to a much shorter wire , and the strips lit up.

Comment: @Justme what if i replace it with a push-pull circuit ? its really cheap to get something like [this](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811151444_onsemi-BC846BPDW1T1G_C232589.pdf). But i do not know if it can do 800Khz no problem

Comment: why not a 74hc? like 74hc1g125? with series termination at the output. make sure Vdd has enough caps with good layout.

Comment: @PeteW im planning to use the [74ABT244](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/74ABT244PW-118/1229268) and i will parallel some channels giving me much more drive current, How much series termination is needed at the output?

Comment: Most logic families will be faster than you need IMO. Slower logic families might be more forgiving of the design / layout you might have, doing it blind w/o scope. Termination should match the cable as closely as you can. 100 ohm is a useful starting point. The single 74HC driver/buffer should have adequate current, 35mA max, but you can get a double

Comment: @PeteW reason i chose that is its cheaper than the single and double versions. not only that it does the leveling shifting for me no extra circuits, most 74hc that is 35mA needs a high voltage of 0.7xVcc(5v). Thats 3.5v which is above my 3.3v logic. It might be overkill but it checks all the boxes.  Anyway, I do have some stocked resistor values , atleast i kinda know that the resistor is a must.

Comment: Oh ok. Then you could use 74HCTxxxx instead of 74HCxxxx ... it has lower V_IH. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

As these are cascadable, and the datasheet claims that they can drive 10m to the next one, why don't you simply put one pixel in your controller and turn it off.  Use it to drive the 10m to the next one.

If you want to make your own driver, then there are two things to watch out for:

1. driving the capacitance of the cable to give you a reasonable risetime
2. avoiding transmission line effects, 10m of line gives a delay of around 50ns, so a risetime around this level risks reflections causing multiple transitions from one edge

The simplest thing to try is probably source termination, this assumes that the receiver approximates an open circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAkD1H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need a beefy buffer that can drive +5V and source 25mA, and can pull down to 0V while sinking 25mA.  The 100R is approximately the cable characteristic impedance.  Note that this will give you very similar output specs to your pixel elements.

25mA is probably enough drive capability as during the transient the driver sees around 200 ohms (the 100R plus Zo of the cable).

You may get away with a driver with lower drive capability, but as you don't have an oscilloscope, you aren't in a great position to debug any issues.

Comment: Yes, they are cascaded. Like seriously >>?? And i checked the datasheet YES THEY CAN DO 10m . BUT i will not do that, to you it might sound stupid but, I will do it the "proper way". But i will test out this method

Comment: It's only a suggestion.  It could double as a status / error indicator.

Comment: Dont take it the wrong way, Your answer is really clever, I just want to fix my circuit mainly :)

Answer (score 2):

You could have tested this idea out using a SPICE simulator. Just for fun, I ran this in LTspice (free and full featured SPICE simulator). R15 needs to be much lower in value due to capacitance from the FET and cable. Four runs were made with the cable capacitance at 1pF, 50pF, 500pF, and 5nF. At 500pF the signal is having a hard time getting above 2.7V and at 5nF it attenuates the signal (essentially what you were getting with R15 = 100k). This sort of level shifter has issues since R15 determines the rise time in conjunction with the output capacitance.

[image: LTspiceSimulation]

Comment: I did my own simulation using ltspice, further reducing the resistance, boy the signal did not look pretty. [Image](https://i.ibb.co/DQcJ5kT/image.png). I would like to simulate a [buffer](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/74AHCT1G126QW5-7/31-74AHCT1G126QW5-7CT-ND/13180600?itemSeq=377997344) in LTspice. What base component should i use

Comment: @DrakeJest To see transmission line effects, you can use a standard SPICE voltage source with a resistor in series (same value as the impedance of your transmission line) with the output along with a SPICE transmission line (_tline_ device in LTspice). If you want to model a device driver, try doing a search for a transistor level 74HCT SPICE model. Of course, the best thing is to have an oscilloscope to see what's happening with actual parts. Pretty hard to design without an oscilloscope. An oscilloscope is a good investment if interested in electronics. USB scopes have come a long way.

Comment: I did some testing and i found somethig interesting, So i tried using an arduino UNO board, it has 5v logic, and it had no problem with the 10 meters, directly onto its GPIO, no buffers or anything. So all i got to figure out now is how to replicate the PUSH/PULL inside